# Minimum of knowledge about different clefs for composing songs

Tags: composition

I have started composing songs and the instrument arrangement since 1 year now.
I have learned guitar from my friend and he taught me treble clef,by searching on internet I had understood the bass clef also.When I started using Muse Score composing software -I have understood the percussion (Drums) notation also.

Now I can notate a melody and instrument arrangement with the understanding of these 3 clefs.I have written around 5 songs now
Please let me know-Is these understanding on 3 clefs are enough for song composition or need to know more clefs.Please let me know the minimum number of clefs required for song composition.

Comment: As Richard says in his answer, treble and bass clef are enough for most communication with other musicians. However, in addition to this you might find it useful to make sure you know about **Transposition**. This would be particularly useful if you are working with wind and brass instruments, or if you need to change keys of songs to suit different voices.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're good to go!

If you were a viola player, you'd want to know alto clef. If you were a trombone or bassoon player, you'd want to know tenor clef. If you were reading Bach from the original manuscripts, you'd want to be fluent in soprano clef.

**But for song composition, treble and bass clef are enough.** (In fact, anyone reading it will appreciate it, because most people don't know the C clefs.)